# Difference between ARMA and ARIMA with d =0?

Tags: r, arima

I'm trying to build up a script to forecast/predict return values on forex currencies (since my data is stationary, differentiation is not required). My question is related to R:

- Can I use Arima (p,d=0,q) instead of ARMA? What would be the
  difference?
- Can I assume that equal result in R packages?

Thank you in advance for your answers!

Comment: The math should be the same. The output could be different, but that is dependent on the package. Just run them both on a sample and decide which output you prefer.

Comment: OK thank you. But for ARMA I could not obtain the best parameters for p and q, so that`s why I have choosen to apply a grid search for ARIMA models and I`ve selected the one with the lowest AIC coeff. But how do I know for ARMA which is the best combination of p and q?

Comment: Now I`m getting an error  In sqrt(diag(x$var.coef)) : NaNs produced when runing this arima m5=arima(train5$train, order=c(7,0,9), method="ML)
summary(m5)
Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: If you edit the post with the code that you are working with that would be helpful. Along with some sample data

Comment: m4=arima(train4$train, order=c(7,0,3))
summary(m4)
Train 4 is a forex data of log returns of the EURJPY couple.